# track user behaviour in a website

Tags: website-design, user-behavior

I have a big database for properties and users will come to search for any property.

For example if a user select 2 Bedrooms in Location = 'XYZ',there will be more than 100000 results.I want to refine those results and show best five of them.

First of all i have some defined parameters which i will also compare with this result like i will see which result has 'Parking' so i will show this one.

Secondly, I want to track user behaviour, For example This user is more interested in this building so i will show that result.

How i can track user behaviour?

Comment: I'm not really following what it is you're asking here. Are you asking for some suggestions on tracking apps / software?

Comment: I want to track user in my website,what are the possible ways for that?Can i do it with out software?

Comment: No. That's the short answer, aside from reasonably anonymous user data (browser, IP, country/city) if you wanted to "track" users you would need to write some custom code or employ a 3rd party system to provide some tracking metrics. This has implications for privacy that you should consider.

Comment: Only IP,City etc will not work..they are not too much usefull to me.Have you seen google?How it will suggest you and will treat you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things, you are talking about can be usually solved by **cookie profiling, tracking and analytics**.
 But thats not an easy thing to do, so the best way would be to buy some third-party applications for such tracking. 
 For example Google can do it, becouse of gathering lots of different information about the user from lots of it services and account connections. 
For more general information about peer groups and interests, you can use http://www.google.com/analytics/  or some things like http://www.personagraph.com/ for example